# auto-advance to next page when iframe video ends in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, iframe

I am trying to embed a vimeo video using iframe in my Qualtrics survey. When this video ends, I want to automatically advance to the next page (i.e., automatically press the "next button"). Before using vimeo, my videos were stored on dropbox and I used the following code for this (the url is not the real one):

```
<video autoplay="" id="video1" height="580" width="740"><source src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6339921/att/fam.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {    
  that = this; 
  document.getElementById('video1').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
  function myHandler(e) {
    if(!e) { 
      e = window.event; 
    }
    that.clickNextButton();  
  }
});
```

However, it seems that I have to use iframe with vimeo, but I am unable to make the auto-advance work (the video will play but the page will not advance). Maybe it is because I am assigning the "ID" the wrong way. Here is the code:

```
<iframe id="player1"  src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/20708824?autoplay=1api=1&player_id=player1&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&background=1&mute=0&loop=0" width="600" height="400" frameborder="0"></iframe>

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {

  that = this;
  var idPlayer = new Vimeo.Player('player1');
  document.getElementByID('player1').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
  function myHandler(e) {
    if(!e) { e = window.event; }
        that.clickNextButton();  
  }
});
```

I am looking for a) an option to fix the iframe code, or b) an option to embed a vimeo video using the old  code that I had used with dropbox videos. 
Thanks so much and I apologize if this all sounds naive, I am not a programmer :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can't add an event listener to an iframe from a different domain. It is called cross-domain scripting and for security reasons isn't allowed by the browser.

You have to use postMessage. There is a JavaScript class already written, but you would have figure out how to integrate it into Qualtrics:

https://github.com/vimeo/player.js